# Why isn't  "useradd" working to add a user to the primary group?

Tags: users

The command I use is:

`sudo useradd -g users tom`

It should add tom to the group *users*, but I can't find tom in *users* when checking */etc/group*.

However, if I just try:

`sudo useradd -G users jim`

I find that jim is added to *users* successfully.

Anyone has ever come across this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Note:** `useradd` is a low-level utility and it is highly recommended you use **`adduser`** (or `usermod`) instead on Ubuntu/Debian systems

- You are better off using the `id -Gn username` command to check primary/secondary membership rather than relying on `/etc/group`
- The `-g` option to `useradd` sets the *primary* (or login) group of a **new user**

  - If set to an *existing* group, this *will not* be reflected in `/etc/group`
  - But you can see the existing GID in `/etc/passwd` or using `id -Gn username`
  - Example (group *izx* is gid 1000):

    ```
    $ sudo useradd -g izx tom
    $ grep ^izx /etc/group
    izx:x:1000:
    $ grep ^tom /etc/passwd
    tom:x:1008:1000::/home/tom:/bin/sh
    $ id -Gn tom
    izx
    ```
- The `-G` option to `useradd` sets the *secondary* (or supplementary) group(s) of a **new user**

  - These memberships *will* be reflected in `/etc/group` and using `id -Gn username`
  - But *not* in `/etc/passwd` (compare to `-g` above)
  - Example (group *izx* is gid 1000):

    ```
    $ sudo useradd -G izx harry
    $ grep ^izx /etc/group
    izx:x:1000:harry
    $ grep ^harry /etc/passwd
    harry:x:1009:1009::/home/harry:/bin/sh
    $ id -Gn harry
    harry izx
    ```